# WebGL Three.js and CSS reset

Tags: css, webgl, css-reset, three.js

Is it OK to use CSS reset together with WebGL Three.js library?
Does it affect anything?

Comment: If they wouldn't affect anything, then why would you use them. :P ( Not a real question.. or judgement.. )

Comment: let's have a website, it has CSS reset and WebGL canvas inside. Does CSS reset interfere the canvas or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three.js works pretty much exclusively with the WebGL context created on a canvas, which is not affected by CSS at all. You can manipulate the canvas itself with CSS libraries, but that doesn't affect how the GL context works in the slightest. As such, the two libraries shouldn't have any problems co-existing.

Comment: Thanks, glad to verify this fact